Does two clocks moving toward each other at the same speed, then decelerating at the same rate coming to a stop create a paradox?
Note I have asked this question previously but upon reflection I realized I was not specific enough, leading to confusion in the answers. I have decided to ask the question again instead of editing my previous question as I think it will simply get buried and unanswered. but I digress.
Say you have two clocks A & B that are a certain distance from each other. They move toward each other at the same speed for a certain period of time, then at a certain distance from each other, both decelerate at the same rate and come to a stop exactly halfway from the initial distance from each other.
This is my understanding of what happens. In the beginning when the two clocks are moving toward each other at the same speed, clock A sees clock B's time going slower than itself and vice versa. Then when they both decelerate at the same rate they both experience the same time dilation, where there is a symmetry. However, Because of the time dilation experienced before the deceleration of each clock, when the two clocks meet, each clock will see the other as being slower than itself creating an asymmetry. This cannot be right so I must be missing something. So my question for you is where is the flaw in my understanding?

Beware that A switches to a noninertial frame and observes B as accelerating both by the noninertial nature of the frame as well as "on its own" where B's own acceleration starts at a different point in time than the switch of frames!

two things: if you edit a question, it gets bumped back up to the front page precisely to keep you from reposting questions. Also, the comments on your original question do indeed contain all the information required to answer the question.
